# How can I set up a BigQuery query with a date range includes the current date

Tags: mysql, sql, google-bigquery

I'm trying to query a database of hits in BigQuery starting at a specified go live date and I want the query to continuously run each day afterwards. Is there a way to prevent hard coding a date range into a query but have the current date instead?

What I've got so far is

```
WHERE SUBSTR(_TABLE_SUFFIX, 1, 8) BETWEEN '20200701' AND '20211231'
```

Its the second date that I want to change to be some sort of variable for the current date?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [CURRENT_DATE()](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/date_functions#current_date) with [FORMAT_DATE()](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/date_functions#format_date):

```
SELECT FORMAT_DATE("%Y%m%d", CURRENT_DATE()) AS formatted;
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks I'll give it a go :)

Comment: The query only returns a result for the month of May, do you know how I can edit it to return values for the days from the 1st to today in May?

Comment: Take a look at [GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/array_functions#generate_date_array)